# Creating a "controller" script for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a program in `Node.js`. I'm pretty new to programming anything other than small javascript functions for websites so please bear with me if my terminology/ideas are totally wrong.

I originally had the entire program in one giant (~500 line) script file. Several people suggested I split it up into separate classes, where each class only has one 'job' to complete. I like this idea as it has helped me really streamline my code and make it more modular and manageable.

My issue is: How do I access these classes from a central file?

For instance, pretend I have 3 classes, in 3 separate javascript files, all containing 3 functions each. I want to access and pass data to/from all of these from one central "controller" script. What's the best way to do this? Can I just `require` it into a variable, then access the script's functions like so?

```
var class1 = require('./class1.js');

class1.function1(); // call the first function contained in class1.js
```

Is such a thing even possible? Again, totally new to this.

Comment: Just `require()` them, like everything else.  What problem are you having?

Comment: You could look into running something like backbone.js on your server. It structures your code into models, routers, and views.

Comment: @SLaks as noted above, I require the script but then how do I access the functions within said script? The sample code above throws an error. EDIT: As in, `class1.js` has a function called `function1` inside of it. How do I call this function from my main script? `class1.function1();` does not work.

Comment: Are you  looking for a way to route web request to specific functions in different files? Say: `GET /clients` triggers function listClients in clientController.js and/or `POST /product` trigger function addProduct in productController.js ? If so I think I might help, otherwise please desconsider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS supports [CommonJS modules](http://www.commonjs.org/specs/modules/1.0/). A CommonJS module provides three global variables: [module](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_module), [exports](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_exports) and [require](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require).
You can export your API by adding to the `exports` object and `require` these files just like other node modules (add `./` to indicate that it is relative to the current file), assign it to a variable and access the values you added to that files `exports` object:

```
// first-module.js

exports.hello = 'world';
exports.num = 23;


// main.js

var first = require('./first-module');

console.log(first.hello);
console.log(first.num);
```

Comment: Quick bit of clarification: If `exports.hello` is a function that calls `num` (another function), but `main.js` only calls `hello()`, do I need to add `num()` to `exports` as well? Or do I only add the functions I'm actively calling from `main.js`?

Comment: Only the functions you are calling. If you don't export them they will be private, which means not accessible from outside your module but exported functions inside the module can still call it just fine.

Comment: gotcha. This means I'll have to modify my classes so that the first function that is called returns the treated object when all the sibling functions are done. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think so. You can just `exports.MyClass = MyClass;` and then use them that way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add functions to the `exports` object in `class1.js`.
`require("./class1")` will return this object.